# extract PCR time value from MPEG TS

Tags: mpeg2-ts

I'm trying to extract the PCR time value from an MPEG-TS packet. According to [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG_transport_stream), the PCR contains 33+6+9 number of bits and also it states that the first 33 bits are based on a 90 kHz clock while the last 9 are based on a 27 MHz clock. I extract the bits that follows adaptation field byte, when the PCR flag is enabled.

The question is, how do I calculate the PCR time stamp value with this 48 (33+6+9) bits I have, by considering the respective clock frequency values.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
PCR(i) = PCR_base(i)*300 + PCR_ext(i)
```

Where (i) is the index of the byte containing the last bit of the program_clock_reference_base field.

Source:

- [PCR measurements](http://www.tek.com/dl/25W_14617_1.pdf)
- Also check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6201926/3194340)

Answer (score 1):

Depending of the accuracy needed by your application, you can work only with the 90kHz clock.
The 27Mhz component is used to detect drift in a broadcasting environment.